# Jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery

Help me to find some jquery plugin like this - http://fr.grandluxuryhotels.com/hotel/hotel-du-palais/offre-speciale/633-imperial-gourmet/   ... Wide photos miving and changing each oother

Comment: Sounds more like an order than a request.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the changing images ... the page you're pointing to is using flash.  Rather than just asking to be pointed to a jQuery plugin (which isn't really, IMHO, a valid question) a better way to go about it would be to 1) Google to see if you could discover a jQuery plugin that supports similar effects, 2) Attempt to create your own custom implementation of the effect since none could be found on the internet or on Stackoverflow, 3) Come to Stackoverflow and ask for help on a problem you're having *implementing* your player.

Answer (score 1):

That site uses Flash to implement that fading into the next picture effect...i've never seen it in jQuery.

The only thing similar i've seen is jCarosel:
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

You can setup moving photos and have them autoscroll